# Trying to create TTT using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am trying to figure out how to implement X's and O's on tic tac toe through javascript when I click on a square on my board. I must create the Xs or O's for the Tic Tac Toe. But I am not sure how to make an X or O. Also I need it to be functional like the actual tic tac-toe game.

Comment: This is most certainly producing an error on the browser console, because `addEventListener` isn't a function on `squares`.  You're selecting *multiple* elements, you'd need to loop over them to interact with them.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML for the tic tac toe board to help further identify the problem?

Comment: You are treating the return of `.querySelectorAll` as an `Element` but it is actually a `NodeList`, you'll have to iterate over it and add event listeners to each element, something like `squares.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener(..))`

Comment: @johnjames you can continue to use divs, but you need to iterate over them in javascript with what Titus posted.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Why did you remove all your code?

Comment: Please stop editing your question to add requirements. Stackoverflow is not meant as a place to post your homework and have someone do it for you. Ethan has already provided a very good working example, but now it's up to you to take that code and finish it. Also, you keep making the question harder to understand; `TTT` is in the title is worse than `Tic Tac Toe`, since `TTT` can mean many things.

Answer (score 2):

You have to **iterate** over each square  because `querySelectorAll` returns multiple nodes which you cannot directly add an eventListener on because `addEventListener` only works for one node at a time.

I also added some CSS to the snippet below so when you run it you can see it working. Ignore this in your final project.

```js
window.onload = () => {
    
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square")

    let currentPlayer = "X";

    squares.forEach(square => {

        square.addEventListener("click", () => {
                
                if (square.innerHTML === "") {
                    square.innerHTML = currentPlayer;
                    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === "X" ? "O" : "X";
                }
    
            });
    });
};

document.querySelector('#reset-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.square').forEach(square => {
        square.innerHTML = "";
    });
});
```

```css
#board {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.square:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="board">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
      <div class="square"></div>
    </div>
    <button id="reset-btn">RESET</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Edit: I changed the above snippet to **alternate** when clicked, which can be used by initializing a variable with the currentPlayer (X or O) and swapping it with a simple ternary statement when clicked. I also added functionality to your reset button!.

Comment: *"create the X's or O's and **have them alternate**."* - This answer looks great, but only inserts X's; missing a key part of the question here 

Comment: @TimLewis Looks like OP edited the question once more. The first time it only included his javascript and I didn't know he wanted them to alternate. I would help him further but wouldn't it be spoonfeeding at that point?

Comment: Yes and no; I'm not sure what's going on with the edits for this question, and like I said, this answer is great as, but it can be better if you answer that other part. You don't have to though, if you think it's "spoon feeding" or doing the hard work for them; your call.

Comment: @TimLewis It looks like all revisions included it, I simply missed it. I edited the answer to include the alternation, thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: That edit made it worse actually  Question, have you played Tic-tac-toe before? By alternate, they mean X, then O, then X, etc., until the board is full; you can't replace a placed X with an O, and vice-versa 

Comment: You'd want to store a variable for which symbol is inserted, then change it on every click (unless clicking a filled square), so first click is an X, send is an O, third is an X, and so-on.

Comment: @TimLewis Hahaha oops, I don't know why I thought it meant switch between O and X when clicked. My apologies, I'll edit it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248801/discussion-between-ethan-r-and-tim-lewis).